# VBA Excel - Non-continuous cells in same row, loop by row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working within a table object, and I need to value-ize or remove rows of data based off a unique reference column. The problem is, this data is broken into non-continuous columns of their own. I should probably show exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
For Each i In Range("Table1[#Headers]")
    If i = "REF" Then
        For Each j In Range("Table1[" & i & "]")
            If j <> j.Offset(-1, 0) Then
                Range("Table1[[#All],[COL01]]").Cells(j.Row, 1) = val(Range("Table1[[#All],[COL01]]").Cells(j.Row, 1))
                Range("Table1[[#All],[COL05]]").Cells(j.Row, 1) = val(Range("Table1[[#All],[COL05]]").Cells(j.Row, 1))
'etc....
            Else:
                Range("Table1[[#All],[COL01]]").Cells(j.Row, 1).ClearContents
                Range("Table1[[#All],[COL05]]").Cells(j.Row, 1).ClearContents
'etc....
            End If
        Next j
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

This finds the "REF" column which is sorted and has multiples of the same value, determines the beginning of each set of similar values {`j <> j.Offset(-1, 0)`}, and if `j` is indeed the beginning of a set, looks at a different column in the same row and does a `val()` on it, effectively turning blanks to zeros. Otherwise, it will clear the contents of that cell...

The problem is.. I have a LOT of "COL"-type columns to work with, and they are not always continuous, and the rows in this data table are 10,000+; the entire process takes forever. Is there a way to do a `Union()`-type range that isn't a writing nightmare? Maybe using arrays/dictionary/something? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In general, it will be much (orders of magnitude) faster to read the entire table into a VBA-array, run your algorithm on the array, then write the array back to the worksheet. However, since this method won't handle formulas, only values, you may have to reproduce the formulas when you are done; or only write back the altered columns.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean? Arrays are kind of new to me...

Comment: You can start with Chip Pearson's discussion [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've managed to find an answer using custom ranges and `Intersect()`

Here's the code I came up with:

```
Dim Rng As Range

For Each i_1 In Range("Table1[#Headers]")
    If i_1 = "REF" Then
        For Each j_1 In Range("Table1[#Headers]")
            If InStr(1, "COL01|COL05|...|...|...", j_1) <> 0 Then
                If Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set Rng = Range("Table1[[#All],[" & j_1 & "]]")
                Else:
                    Set Rng = Union(Rng, Range("Table1[[#All],[" & j_1 & "]]"))
                End If
            End If
        Next j_1
        For Each j_2 In Range("Table1[" & i_1 & "]")
            If j_2 <> j_2.Offset(-1, 0) Then
                Intersect(Rng, Rows(j_2.Row)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
            Else:
                Intersect(Rng, Rows(j_2.Row)).ClearContents
            End If
        Next j_2
    Exit For
    End If
Next i_1
```

See once it finds the `"REF"` column, it establishes all the required columns into a `Union()` range. Then it intersects those columns with each row in `Table1` via another loop with its own conditions. If you can find a better way to create this let me know, but I found it dramatically shortens the processing time.